# Limit Size and Type of an Uploaded File with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

forgive the beginner question, but I am trying to limit the size and type of an uploaded file via TypeScript.

My HTML currently looks like this:

```html
      <label class="custom-file-upload">
        <input type="file" id="fileName" accept=".xls,.xlsx, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel" onchange="validateFileType()"/>
          <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload"></i> 
          Upload
      </label>
```

While my TypeScript file looks like this:

```
  private validateFileType() {
    const fileName = (document.getElementById('fileName')as HTMLInputElement).value;
    const idxDot = fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1;
    const extFile = fileName.substr(idxDot, fileName.length).toLowerCase();

    if (extFile === 'xls' || extFile === 'xlsx') {
        // TO DO
    } else {
        // Notification here
    }
  }

  private validateFileSize() {
    const fileName = (document.getElementById('fileName')as HTMLInputElement);

    // fileName.onchange = function() {
      if (fileName.files[0].size > 2097152) {
        // Notification here
        fileName.value = '';
      }
    };
```

Currently, it doesn't work, but I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify "it doesn't work". How doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I have a notification in place on my `else` statement. I don't get anything when I try to upload. Same with `validateFileSize`, I still am able to upload files above 2MB. My apologies.

Comment: Are you using vue.js? Which version? I think your event binding is wrong

Comment: Yup, using Vue.js. `npm list vue` shows `2.6.10`. If ever, I'm just looking for a way to Limit Size and Type of an Uploaded File with Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a Vue.js expert here, but it seems to me that your event binding syntax is wrong.

Vue.js 2.x:

```
<input type="file" v-on:change="validateFileType"/>
```

Vue.js 3.x:

```
<input type="file" @change="validateFileType"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your first suggestion with Vue.js 2.x worked! Any idea how to make `validateFileSize` work, though?

Comment: It's not clear what's your issue with `validateFileSize`. You're just not calling it anywhere from what I see. Also you need to handle both conditions for file's size (valid/invalid): i.e. if size > 2097152 alert user, else send file to server.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Already fixed what I needed to fix. Thank you again for the help!